# NHibernate - Sytem.OutOfMemoryException thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, nhibernate, orm

I'm getting a System.OutOfMemoryException when trying to fetch 185 records from DB using ASP.NET MVC and NHibernate. 
Here is the code snippet of the method from the Repository class:

```
public IList<RequestForm> GetForFullExport(RequestFormSearchCriteria searchCriteria,     string[] restrictRoles)
{
...

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<RequestForm>()
   .CreateAlias("RequestMember", "RequestMember")
   .CreateAlias("RequestFormStatu", "RequestFormStatu")
   .SetFetchMode("RequestMember", FetchMode.Eager)
   .SetFetchMode("RequestFormStatu", FetchMode.Eager);

DetachedCriteria criteriaLang = DetachedCriteria.For<RequestForm>("af")
    .SetFetchMode("RequestFormsLanguages", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("RequestFormsLanguages.LanguageMember", FetchMode.Eager);

DetachedCriteria criteriaDoc = DetachedCriteria.For<RequestForm>("af")
    .SetFetchMode("RequestFormsDocuments", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("RequestFormsDocuments.DocumentMember", FetchMode.Eager);

criteriaLang.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", NHibernate.CriteriaTransformer.Clone(criteria).SetProjection(NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Id())));
criteriaDoc.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", NHibernate.CriteriaTransformer.Clone(criteria).SetProjection(NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Id())));

//Add sort
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.SIdx))
{
    criteria.AddOrder(new Order(searchCriteria.SIdx, searchCriteria.SOrd == "asc"));
}

var multiResult = Session.CreateMultiCriteria()
    .Add(criteria)
    .Add(criteriaLang)
    .Add(criteriaDoc)
    .List();

...
}
```

And here is where the code breaks with System.OutOfMemory exception - at Session.CreateMultiCriteria().
I've extracted the SQL query that NHibernate is generating and executed it directly in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio and I got the results very fast (185 rows).

The application is actually trying to export the jQuery grid rows to CSV file and above mentioned method is called in this process.
The crash is happening only when I try to export all rows. When I export several rows - everything works fine.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put stack trace, but, anyway, I've located the problem. I'll post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same problem. You can use StatelessSession and set batch size. it solves the problem related bulk data insertion into database.
for more reference : http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/30/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernate-s-stateless-sessions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part of the code is `criteriaDoc` which is searching for DB records that contains MS Word files. Those files have large size and that is why I got this exception. I wasn't aware of this, because I took over this application recently. I found it out now, while investigating.

Basically, my problem is solved, because I don't need doc files for the grid export.

Still, it would be nice if someone can answer what are the limitations of fetching large data using NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setMaxResult so it doesn't fetch all the rows into the list.